# Correction formula for alcoholmeter

Tags: analytical-chemistry, alcohols, density

I need to find the formula, if there is one, which would calculate the correction of alcoholmeter.

Basically convert observed %ABV (Alcohol by volume) to actual %ABV using the sample's temperature.

I know the correction tables, but I am looking for the formula or do I have to use tables?.

Comment: No doubt there is a formula. Not knowing what you are measuring or what table you are using, I can't find the formula for you.

Comment: So this is a table I am talking about
http://homedistiller.org/correctiontable.pdf
They even have online calculator for it
http://homedistiller.org/calcs/husker_temp_convert.php

Comment: and I am measuring  '_fruit spirit_' if it is called like that in english. I get distillate measure percante content  by volume of ethanol at some temperature, but then I need to correct that measurment to 20°C.

Comment: @MaxW Forget to mention you :]

Comment: You are probably better off using the tables.  Are you trying to put this formula into a spreadsheet or something?  The best you can probably do is plot a bunch of data from the table and come up with some high-order polynomial that fits it. Just be sure you understand the consequences of doing it that way (i.e. massive errors).  Take a look at the equations used to come up with that table.  Usually if there is a simple equation available, nobody would go through the trouble of making a table ;)

Comment: Well, I just noticed that the online calculator has the option of looking values up from the table or using an equation.  This is where I would start to dig.

Comment: I'm too lazy to dig for this. The technique uses a hydrometer which is probably calibrated to read %ABV at 20 C. So you need to find an equation for the density of an ethanol-water mixture as a function of ethanol concentration and temperature.

Comment: @airhuff - they make a table because calculating a polynomial expansion blows most folks mind. The computer program at the site no doubt uses an equation.  See: http://zd2.chem.uni.wroc.pl/pliki/alcohm.pdf

Comment: starting at http://web2.airmail.net/sgross/fermcalc/fermcalc_alcohol.html you should be able to find what you need...

Comment: @MaxW, probably shouldn't have even brought up the polynomial thing. That said, the problem I've seen is that with modern spreadsheets it's _too easy_ for anyone to calculate up to a 9th order polynomial and say ~"look, I've fitted it with r^2 =0.9999" !

Comment: @MaxW, airhuff thank you both. I am trying to put this formula into computer program. I will probably try that formula at [page 12](http://zd2.chem.uni.wroc.pl/pliki/alcohm.pdf), if it won't work I will map the data table somehow.

Comment: You'd have better luck using equation 7 on this webpage http://web2.airmail.net/sgross/fermcalc/fermcalc_alcohol.html

Comment: @MaxW I know it is more simple. But let's say I can not obtain brix value. 
But I have solved the density equation. Is there a way how to get percentage content of ethanol by volume from that density value? Sorry I am really noob in this.

Comment: To convert between ABW (% by weight) and ABV (% by volume) either use Table 3b from [OIML Alcoholometric Tables](http://www.itecref.com/pdf/OIML_Alcoholometric_Tables.pdf) or formula provided there at the bottom of page 5: `ABV = (ϱ(ABW)/789.24)*ABW` where ϱ(ABW) is R-K function decribed on page 12 of ABW at 20°C

Comment: Not a formula, but for anyone looking for an up to date calculator that gives reasonable-sounding results (a lot of the links on the other comments and answer are dead) this page seems to do it: https://www.essentialdistilling.com/resources/alcohol-dilution-and-proofing-calculator It also has many other useful calculators or related tasks.

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same question recently. And there is no simple answer. Tables (like ones from *International critical tables of numerical data, physics, chemistry and technology* or [this](https://www.ttb.gov/foia/Gauging_Manual_Tables/Table_1.pdf)) are still the 1st hand source. Formulas used are just approximating this data. Check formula [here](http://www.oiv.int/public/medias/5158/oiv-ma-as312-01a.pdf#page=8) on page 8 (to get the temperature-corrected ABV you have to invert it by solving non-linear function). Alternatively check [this recent study](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:uavxMX8IwnsJ:https://www.mdpi.com/2311-5637/4/3/72/pdf%20&cd=7&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=ru&client=firefox-b). To convert between ABV (alcohol by volume, %) and density (specific gravity SG, g/cm<sup>3</sup>) you may use [this approximation](https://www.bestcustomwriting.com/images/samples/lab-report/sample-lab-report-mla.pdf):

$$\mathrm{SG} = -0.002\cdot\mathrm{ABV} + 1.0012$$

PS. There is an unconfirmed formula at [vinolab](http://www.vinolab.hr/calculator/hydrometer-temperature-correction-en31):

> The hydrometer temperature correction for SG is performed with this expression:
>
> $$\text{corrected-reading} = r \times \frac{(1.00130346 - (0.000134722124 \cdot t) + (0.00000204052596 \cdot t^2)\ - (0.00000000232820948 \cdot t^3))} {(1.00130346 - (0.000134722124 \cdot c) + (0.00000204052596 \cdot c^2)\ - (0.00000000232820948 \cdot c^3))}$$
>
> where: $r$ = reading and $c$ = calibration temperature. This expression is based on °F, so the temperatures are first converted.

With some sample values it gave me results close to the table' ones (I have converted ABV to SG, amended as per temperature and formula above and finally converted back to ABV).

Comment: I think it wouldn't hurt if you include the formulas/data from each report you are referring to. URLs tend to rot over time. Also, the last formula taken from the report written by a student leaving *John Doe* from the template on the front page doesn't look convincing. Also, a tip: you can add `#page=<number>` (e.g. `#page=8` ) at the end of the PDF's URL so that others open the document on that very page.

Comment: Formulas there are quite complex for my markdown skill. I have checked John Doe's formula against [this data](https://wissen.science-and-fun.de/chemistry/chemistry/density-tables/ethanol-water-mixtures/). It gives 0.8% discrepancy at worst.